# Mule ESB Enterprise trial - Error Java Service Wrapper requires a License Key

Tags: mule, mule-studio

1.- Go to http://www.mulesoft.com/management-console-mule-esb, then click Download.

2.- Fill out the registration form.

3.- On the Enterprise trial page, click the appropriate button to download the Runtime bundle for your operating system.

4.- Extract the file.

5.- Navigate to the bin folder, then double-click the mule executable file.

6.- Mule Console print the next in the console:

The Java Service Wrapper requires a License Key to activate the
software.  License Keys can be purchased on the Java Service Wrapper
web site:
  http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase

You can also immediately obtain a one-month Free trial license:
  http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

License Keys can be generated for any of the following HostIds.
  HostId(s):
    0800270000dc (#1)
    9cb654a292c8 (#2)

--- The Mule has not started.

¿What is the solution for start the Mule Esb Trial Version?.

Comment: Your question probably should be sent to whoever supports the product you are trying to use. It does not look like there is any coding problem to be solved...

Comment: Yes, the problem is more of configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed:

1.- Go to http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/spanish/requestTrial.jsp

2.- Generate the Agreement of Licence TSILA-201404040001.

3.- Create trial Licence with the

> HostId(s): 0800270000dc (#1) 9cb654a292c8 (#2)

4.- View Licence:
wrapper.license.type=xxx
wrapper.license.id=xxxx
wrapper.license.licensee=xx
wrapper.license.host_id=xxx
wrapper.license.features=pro, 64bit, trial
wrapper.license.upgrade_term.begin_date=2014-04-04
wrapper.license.upgrade_term.end_date=2014-05-04
wrapper.license.lease_term.begin_date=2014-04-04
wrapper.license.lease_term.end_date=2014-05-04
wrapper.license.key.1=7262-2a41-6ee2-1e5b
wrapper.license.key.2=8695-0f4e-6e4f-70e8
wrapper.license.key.3=44b5-7bbf-6eaa-eded
wrapper.license.key.4=8465-91d6-15ab-4383

5.- Copy  this to  end of the file mule_ee_3.4.2\conf\wrapper.conf

1. Mule Start.